# Wrap around C++ vector like in Python

Tags: c++, python, list, iterator

I want to "wrap" around a list/vector in C++ like in Python. Basically I want to shift elements from the end of the list to beginning of the list. I don't want to have to explicitly make a new list.

In Python I can write something like:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

q = collections.deque(my_list)
q.rotate(3)
#deque([3, 4, 5, 1, 2])
```

I looked at deque in the STL but I don't see anything similar to rotate. Seems like there should be an easy way to do this with iterators, or something similar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are looking for [`std::rotate`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/rotate/) from the standard library, which offers an easy way to do this with iterators.

```
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<T> v /* = populate() */;
std::rotate(v.begin(), v.begin() + 3, v.end());
```

Any forward iterator can be used, so this works on most (sequence) containers.

Comment: Also note that depending on how many elements you rotate relative to the container length, `deque` or even `list` may perform (significantly) better.

Comment: @MarkB: How so? It appears that `rotate` is implemented via `swap` on a per-element basis, without changing the the underlying container...?

Comment: Woops, you wouldn't be able to use `rotate` and would have to implement it manually with pop/push functions or `splice` in the case of `list`. Given that, I'm sure it's a premature optimization.

Comment: @MarkB: Well, you couldn't use `+3`, but rather you should say `std::next(v.begin(), 3)`, and indeed once you have that iterator, it'd be better to do a `splice`.

Comment: @KerreckSB so is the computational complexity  O(n) where n is the number of elements to be swapped?

Comment: @LeviX: Yes. As Markb points out, you can do better with a linked list, which you can rotate by node rather than by value (i.e. you don't do any swapping at all).

Answer (score -2):

You could use

```
#include <algorithm>
std::reverse(my_list.begin(),my_list.end());
```

or use

```
reverse_iterator rbegin();
```

to loop backward in the vector.